# AJAX not separating JSON string

Tags: php, ajax, json

I'm using a star ratings system to display rating data from SQL. Each item that can be rated has unique identifyer variable $id and each rating in ratings tabl has unique identifyer $storyidr. I would like this script to display:

1. the average rating
2. the number of times the item has been rated.

The values are retirevable but they display on the page together and I can't see how to seperate them. FOr example, for an item that has an average rating of 4 and has been rated 200 times. when user clicks the data returns via AJAX looking like:

- For 'response1'     4"200"
- For 'response2'     4"200"

I would like to be able to seperate them to look like:

- For 'response1'       4
- For 'response2'       200

html page

```
   <div id="products" style="">
     <div class="rateit" data-storyidr="<?php echo $id; ?>">
     </div>
      <div class="averagevote">
        <div style="display:block;" id="response<?php echo $id; ?>"><?php echo $avgratep; ?></div><br>
         <div style="display:block;" id="response2<?php echo $id; ?>">RaTeD <?php echo $rankcount; ?> TiMeS</div>
        </div>
       </div>
   <?php endwhile; mysqli_close($connection); ?>

   <script type ="text/javascript"> 
      $('#currentslide .rateit').bind('rated reset', function (e) { 
          var ri = $(this); 
          var value = ri.rateit('value'); 
          var storyidr = ri.data('storyidr'); 
          ri.rateit('readonly', true); 
      $.ajax({
      dataType : 'json', 
      url: 'rate.php', 
      data: {storyidr: storyidr, value: value}, 
      type: 'POST', 
      success: function (data) { 
          $('#response'+storyidr).replaceWith('Avg rating ' + data.avg + '/5'); 
          $('#response2'+storyidr).replaceWith('Rated ' + data.cnt + ' times');

      }, 
           error: function (jxhr, msg, err) {
           $('#response').append('<li style="color:red">' + msg + '</li>');
      }
  }); 
   }); 
    </script>
```

PHP

```
 <?PHP  
            $storyidr=$_POST['storyidr'];
        $mysqli = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbusername,$dbpasswd,$database_name) or die ("Couldn't connect to server.");
         if (mysqli_connect_errno($mysqli))
           {
           echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
           }
        $sql  = "INSERT INTO ratings (storyidr, rank, entry_date) VALUES ('$_POST[storyidr]','$_POST[value]',now());"; 
        $sql .= "SELECT AVG(rank) AS avrank, COUNT(rank) AS countrank FROM ratings WHERE storyidr = $storyidr";
        if($mysqli->multi_query($sql))
        {   $mysqli->next_result();
        if ($result = $mysqli->store_result())
        { 
        $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $avrank = $data['avrank'];
        $countrank = $data['countrank'];
        $avrankr = round($avrank,2);
        if(is_null($avrank)){$avrank ="null";}
                  echo json_encode(array('avg' => $avrankr, 'cnt' => $countrank));

        }
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: `$.ajax({dataType : 'json', ... });`

Comment: You JS file, where you've got part with AJAX call. Just like other options...

Comment: @lazel Removing brackets and adding lines of code to question are not appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only use `json_encode()` once and only echo the result of that function. Doing it more than once invalidates your json:

```
    else
    {
       $results = array();
       $results['av'] = $avrankr;
       $results['cnt'] = $countrank;

       echo json_encode($results);
    }
```

Then, in your javascript, you can access `data.av` and `data.cnt` directly:

```
$('#response'+storyidr).replaceWith('Avg rating ' + data.av +'/5'); 
$('#response2'+storyidr).replaceWith(data.cnt);
```

You could also set the `dataType` parameter in your ajax call as mentioned by @barell, but normally jQuery will figure that out correctly already.

**Edit:** To avoid the `undefined` errors you are getting you should do something like:

```
$results = array('status' => 'fail');
...
if () {
    ...

      if ($result)
      {
        $results['status'] = 'success';
        $results['av'] = $avrankr;
        $results['cnt'] = $countrank;
      }
}

echo json_encode($results);
```

Now you can check for `data.status` first in the success callback of your ajax call and take the appropriate action:

```
success: function (data) {
   if (data.status === 'fail') {
      // show a warning message somewhere, this is just an example
      alert('No results found!');
   } else {
      $('#response'+storyidr).replaceWith('Avg rating ' + data.av + '/5'); 
      $('#response2'+storyidr).replaceWith('RaTeD ' + data.cnt + ' TiMeS'); 
   }
},
```

Comment: Made suggestions, I'm getting an error:  "Avg Rating is undefined" I'll edit code to include changes. I'm thinking it's a jquery error? thank you @jeroen! please offer suggestable fix if possible!

Comment: @buzrw It would seem you have entered the `if` loop in your php script. You should do a `console.log(data)` in your success function (in javascript) to see what it contains exactly.

Comment: I didn't think php would give a 'undefined' error code. I thought that was a jquery error @jeroen

Comment: @buzrw It is, but when you enter the `if(!$result)` part in your php script, you are not setting the correct array variables so they will be undefined in your javascript when you try to access them. You should check for `data.status` first and to make it complete you should add `$results['status'] = 'success';` in the `else` section so that it is always defined when you get the results back in your ajax call.

Comment: i can't thank you enough. I am likely not following your instructions correctly and still getting the same error I posted most current version of code. If you could take one more look. thank you in advaance

Comment: @buzrw I added the javascript necessary to process the result. If that does not solve the problem, you need to narrow down where the problem is, in the javascript or the php, check the Net tab of the developers tools to see what comes back from the server.

Comment: you just solved it. Also, I needed this all along: dataType : 'json', Without it data.avg and data.cnt  aren't understood. I was going off an aspx based code when writing this and that may explain me not including the 'datatype'. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is you don't set the correct header. In the php file, before any output, put this:

```
header('Content-type: text/json');
```

And also, instead of write two objects, write it as an array:

```
echo json_encode(array('avg' => $avrankr, 'cnt' => $countrank));
```

Now it should work

Then, in your Javascript you will access this data like this:

```
$('#response'+storyidr).replaceWith('Avg rating ' + data.avg +'/5');
$('#response'+storyidr).replaceWith(data.cnt); // Suppose you want the count here
```

Comment: I think this is on the right track but I'm getting a jquery error that says the value for data.avg is undefined

Comment: If you are using the updated version of your code, it's `data.av`, because of this line: `$results['av'] = $avrankr;`

Comment: @ lazel I've posted in my most current code. I can't seem to find the error. I looked at what you said and I'm using .av as suggested. Any help would be amazing and thank you in advance.

Comment: I've made a little change in your code, just added the right `header` before you send out data.